# Whats wrong with this Pattern Program in C

Tags: c

I was creating the following pattern through C Language

Pattern: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoKm0.jpg

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=1, j=1,k=1;
    while(i<=6)
    {
        if(i!=1 || i!=6)
        {
         while(j<=5)
         {
             if(j!=3)
             {
                 printf("*");
             }
             else
             {
                 printf(" ");
             }
             j++;
         }
        }
        else
        {
          while(k<=5)
          {
              printf("*");
              k++;
          }
        }
        i++;
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me by describing the error I am doing. Please help me with the right code.

Comment: What is it supposed to do, and in what way is it not doing it?

Comment: `if (i != 1 || i != 6)` will **always** be true.

Comment: Why is this tagged design-patterns

Comment: He's designing a pattern /s

Answer (score 0):

Reset your temporary variables between loops.  Take a closer look at your if statements.  You aren't printing any newlines.

Comment: Can you please help me with the exact code, that I need to change

Comment: Fred already helped you with the broken if statement.  Please attempt the other two comments on your own.  It's worth learning.